# Java ProcessBuilder holding child processes

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm starting a process using the Java ProcessBuilder Class:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "My shortcut");
```

This shortcut, when manually run creates a few log files within seconds. But when run as above, the log files are not getting written unless the program exits. I need to check whether the files are generated in the same test class where I'm starting it. 
What might be going wrong ?

Comment: You should include more code showing your call. Have you called start() and added thread to consume / handle standard output / error stream of your process? If not it might appear to freeze unexpectly.

Comment: Yes, here is my block:
  try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "My shortcut.lnk");
        Process a = pb.start();

        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

After this I can see my process started in the Task Manager, but the file creation has the issue.

Comment: Double check it isn't an issue with where the current working directory is. Also if your process writes a lot to its standard output, you might try consuming the output stream in a thread as this can cause issues too. See example code in my answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293943/java-process-builder-manually-pipe/61565069

Comment: Thanks!! That solved my issue.